# what does class="#language("x.dir") mean in HTML?

Tags: html, tags, velocity

I'm fairly new the HTML and markup / velocity documents. Know basic html but I don't understand what this means:

```
<html class="#language("lang.dir")" dir="#language("lang.dir")" lang="$w3c_language_id">
```

may be someone can shed some light on each attribute? Thanks!

Comment: This is probably some kind of templating engine.  The `#language("lang.dir")` (and `$w3c_language_id`) will be replaced with the language.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a feature of Velocity. It's definitely not an HTML thing. Have you read the Velocity docs?

Comment: why down-rate the question, care to comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are variables of the serverside language /template engine which are getting replaced resulting in something useful *similar* to this:

```
<html class="ltr" dir="ltr" lang="en">
```

A detailed description for the attributes can be found on [MDN - HTML Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Attributes). Basically `lang` is the language of the document and `dir` is the text-direction (left-to-right or right-to-left).